# I can't pass current user outside the Parse.User.currentAsync().then(function(user)){}

Tags: javascript, react-native, parse-platform

I want to get the current user to use in public but outside the  Parse.User.currentAsync().then(function(user) current user is undefined, How can I pass it to a variable ??

```
 var userName;
 Parse.User.currentAsync().then(function(user) {
           userName =  user.get('username')  

   });

 alert(userName) //undefined

 ......

 user.equalTo("username", userName); //userName is undefined
 user.find().then(results => {

  for(const result of results) { ....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const user = await Parse.User.currentAsync();
alert(user.getUsername());
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have to define an async function to use await and I can't pass currentUser from async function

Comment: Why not? Paste your actual complete code of how you are trying to do this. Maybe I can help you.

Comment: I complete it , thank you very much for your help